# How to translate country names

Tags: i18n-l10n

I need to translate the names of countries in drupal. I am using `countries_get_list`, looping through the array and saving it in another array but wrapping the country names in `t()`. I'm not so so sure but it seems this isn't working.
I was doing something like

```
$new_array = array();
foreach(countries_get_list() as $key => name) {
    $new_array[$key] = t($name);
}
return $new_array;
```

Comment: But where did you post this code? And do you have translated strings in your database, ready to be used?

Comment: I needed to generate an select box, so this code is in a function I wrote to generate options for the select box.

Answer (score 1):

You should never use t() to translate variables, unless the text that the variable holds has been passed through t() elsewhere:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/t/73#sec_translating_vars

In this case country_get_list() calls _country_get_predefined_list(), and inside this function country names are passed through t():

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21iso.inc/function/_country_get_predefined_list/7

So, if you have country strings translated in your database (as Molot says) translation should work.

Comment: So if I go ahead and translate the country names, they'll automatically be used in without needing to translate? Secondly it seems the custom module a colleague is using for the translations doesn't show the country names or any string not wrapped in t().

Comment: When t() is called with a string as parameter this string is available to be translated. As _get_country_predefined_list() calls t() with country names those country names should be available as strings to translate if this function is called (I usppose this fucntion hasbeen already called in your system). So, your code is right, you will get a localized country names array.